# How to remove ActionBar.Tab strip in honeycomb?

Tags: android, tabs, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I am using ActionBar.Tab in my application. The default ActionBar.Tab has blue color strip. How can i remove it or change the color of the strip(i showed an example image below)? Is there any possible way? Thanks in advance for your answer:)

[image: I want to remove the blue strip line from the AcionBar.Tab]

Answer (score 0):

**Theme.Notitlebar**
You could be use this feature ..

Comment: How this works for me in HoneyComb to disappear strip of ActionBar.Tab??

Comment: you would be remove from xml view file directly, not doing another extra coding there.